# How can I find out when the computer shuts down after executing the shutdown command?

Tags: c#, windows, admin, shutdown

The user ran the command "shutdown -s -t 8000" on the command line. I need to write code in C# that will return the exact date and time when the computer will be turned off.
I tried to get information from the windows event log:

```
int shutdownEventId = 1074;
string queryString = $@"*[System/EventID={shutdownEventId}]";
EventLogQuery query = new EventLogQuery ( "System", PathType.LogName, queryString );
```

But the log only contains information about when and by whom the shutdown command was executed. Then I tried using schtasks. But I also didn’t find any information about the computer shutdown time. It appears that the shutdown utility is not creating tasks in the task scheduler.
I found this old article: https://web.archive.org/web/20160604093253/http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/windows-nt-6-shutdown-process.html
Here we are talking about a process called "winlogon". But it is not specified how its flags can be read.
So... how can I get the exact date and time the computer shut down after running the shutdown command?

Comment: _"that will return the exact date and time when the computer will be turned off"_ - "will be" or "has been" ?

Comment: And I just checked: The last thing in my EventLog yesterday is a "Kernel-Power" 107 ... that at least hints to something shutdown-related.

Comment: "Will be". It is assumed that the user has scheduled the shutdown using the Shutdown command.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the time when command was executed, can you get executed command text too? If is it so, you can just add time in seconds from command text to command execution time

Comment: No, I couldn't get the command text.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).